# How to disable showcase view in Android emulator

Tags: android, jenkins, android-emulator, cucumber, calabash-android

I'm using `Android` emulator in `Jenkins` to run functional tests (`Cucumber`). Everything works fine if the emulator doesn't contain `showcase view` at the start.

But if there is a `showcase view` my tests fail, because application runs behind this view.

[image: screenshot]

I've tried to send `keyevents` using `adb` to the emulator before using it:

```
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_MENU;
```

but it doesn't help. I've tried `KEYCODE_MENU`, `KEYCODE_BACK` and other [keys](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html), but they don't disable this view.

I guess this property should be available as a `system preference` in the `Android`, but I can't find it :(

How can I disable `showcase view` in emulator? I have access to the emulator using `adb`.

---

**UPDATE**

There's no such flag which can be set in emulator [config file](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html) or passed to emulator at the start.

And I still don't have a clean solution for this, but few workarounds exist. And that's understandable as showcase view is just a view from Launcher application and logic for that is inside Launcher application.

- *tricky way, but universal*: Prepare custom Android Launcher application with disabled showcase (based on [AOSP Launcher](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher2/)) and pre-install (replace default launcher) it on target emulator.
- *manual way, not universal*: gather list of emulators used and coordinates of OK button on those, and send appropriate touch coordinates upon emulator start (as [Christopher Orr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/234938/christopher-orr) proposed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to send a tap event, for example:

```
adb shell input tap 700 900
```

That would tap at approximately the correct x,y pixel coordinate for that button on a Nexus 4.

Comment: Yes, it will work. But I have a lot of emulators with different screen sizes :(